# Paraview running error in libmpi

Tags: mpi, openmpi, paraview

I installed Paraview from source following the instructions in [this site](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install) and built it successfully with mpi and shared libraries. Then from usr/bin/ I ran Paraview as indicated but it gives me this error:

```
./paraview
/usr/lib/paraview/paraview: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_real
```

I as read from some sites I Should set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.This variable is empty when printing echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Should I set this variable and to what?

Comment: Any chance that you have two competing MPI installations? Looks like an inconsistent environment setup. It's not really possible to help you without more information.

Comment: Yes I first installed mpicxx  installed before Paraview. This is the result of mpicxx version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Further information like what?

Comment: I found it. This command solves the problem: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH , where usr/lib/ is the location of the shared libfile libmpi_cxx.so